# Wix MSI Bootstrapper using just .Net Core

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, .net-core-3.1, wix3.11

Wix MSI Bootstrapper using just .Net Core

I have an application that will contain Windows Services and a UI all compiled in .Net Core 3.1.  It will not be self-contained - it will require .Net Core 3.1 to be installed.  I need to create a WIX bootstrapper to install some prerequisites and also to show the user a custom user interface.

Questions:

1. How can I verify .Net Core 3.1 is installed?  I have done it before for the
   full .Net framework, but not the .Net Core.  Is there a value I can
   place in BootstrapperCore.config for supportedRuntime for .NET Core
   3.1?
2. Assuming I can do #1, in my BootstrapperCore.config, do I simply
   place the name of custom .Net Core 3.1 installer custom UI in
   wix.bootstrapper/host/assemblyName attribute?  What do I put in
   wix.bootstrapper/host/supportedFramework/version?

My end goal is to be able to run the installer on a clean Windows system that does not have the full .Net Framework or .Net Core 3.1.  I would expect that once you run the installer, it would install .Net Core 3.1 and then bring up my bootstrapper custom UI.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for a .NET Core BA was recently added in v4 - [#6108](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6108). Starting the .NET Core runtime is [completely different](http://lists.wixtoolset.org/pipermail/wix-users-wixtoolset.org/2020-May/009052.html) from starting the .NET Framework runtime.

.NET Core package groups were recently added in v4 - [#6099](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6099).

Comment: Glad to hear it will be supported in v4.  However, it does not appear that I can use that now for a production system.  It does not appear to be released yet and there does not appear to be any documentation on the docs page (says "(coming soon)").  I similarly could not find a download for it either.  Do you have an ETA for when this will be released?  Until it is released, I may have to install the full framework for just the installer and install .net core for program.  Thanks for the reply.  Please let me know.

Comment: Like I said in the issue, v4's timeline is "hopefully sometime this year?". These days, it should be very rare if you actually need to install the full framework, provided you can target a low enough version.

Comment: That's a good point.  I was targeting full 4.8 before because that is what our installed software used.  Thanks.